# Warning: Object of class Magento\Framework\Phrase could not be converted to int product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml on line 26

Tags: product, magento2.4, product-listing, store-front

Can anyone have faced the below error while opening the product listing page at the storefront?

Running instance on the Magento version 2.4 vanilla. No third-party modules/themes were installed.

A stack trace is as follows:

```
report.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: Object of class Magento\Framework\Phrase could not be converted to int in /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml on line 26 in /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62
-Stack trace:
-#0 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml(26): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler()
-#1 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('...')
-#2 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render()
-#3 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar/Interceptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView()
-#4 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml(21): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar\Interceptor->fetchView()
-#5 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('...')
-#6 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render()
-#7 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar/Interceptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView()
```

Answer (score 10):

The issue got fixed but somehow it was not included in the Magento 2.4.5-p1 release. This most likely will be fixed in the Magento 2.4.5-p2 patch which is  planned to be released in March 2023 ([Release plan](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/planning/schedule.html)).

The fix can be looked up here ([Issue fixing commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb55549cd3016987663272e7ffe3f452c8d6e40d)). The fix looks like this:

```
                <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_key) ?>"
                    <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)):?>
                        selected="selected"
                    <?php endif ?>>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(
                        is_numeric($_limit) ? $localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit) : $_limit
                    ) ?>
                </option>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix is not included in 2.4.5-p2 either.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5-p2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml

Answer (score 3):

It took a while to find out the root cause of this issue, there is a code commit a while ago that broke.

For a quick fix, look for the below line code mostly Line26, and remove the format-number function for `All`. It's not typecasting error, it is an warning related to the localization of Arabic numbers.

**From:**

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit)) ?>
```

**To**

```
<?php if (strtoupper($_key) == 'ALL'): ?>
     <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_limit)) ?>
<?php else: ?>
     <?= $block->escapeHtml($localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit)) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This usually happens when a value for the system configuration field "***Allow All Products per Page***" (`catalog/frontend/list_allow_all`) is selected as "**yes**"

Ref.: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/00fb26bfa86d302cf8ade46ca133b8b9c7f303d6#diff-f50afb0f7a81350c4dd383269f534abc0ce3acb99c431811fc94f7ebe13f68e4R26

Comment: This is still an issue on Magento ver. 2.4.5-p4 with "Allow All Products per Page" set to "yes". Fixed with your snippet in template template for limiter.phtml

Answer (score 0):

The default template looks like this:

```
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit):?>
            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_key) ?>"
                <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)):?>
                    selected="selected"
                <?php endif ?>>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit)) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is line 26

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit)) ?>
```

for some reason you have here `$_limit` as a translatable text insted a numerical value.
Check what the method `$block->getAvailableLimit()` returns. Make sure the re are translatable texts...
You can also try to see what happens when you replace `$_limit` with `$_limit->render()`

Comment: Thanks, @Marjus for giving insight.

Comment: @Marius, I get this error immediately after upgrading Magento to 2.4.5. Can you share any insights into what might've caused this?